# trigger a method when a method (associated with an object) has been called

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, triggers, action, dependency-properties

i am calling some `web services` in my wp7 app using `postClient` (a dll incuded, which provides an interface to call the web services easily)
the sample code--->

```
        PostClient wbclient = new PostClient(parameters);
        wbclient.DownloadStringAsync( //some uri );
        wbclient.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, e) => {  //some code }
```

i'v used these particular statements many where 
now **i want to call a specific common method** whenever the `DownloadStringAsync` called of `PostClient`  `object`, and so that i'v declared this `PostClient` `object` on top and initializing it every time whenever needed but how to attach some property or event handler or trigger to this `PostClient` `object` at same when declared.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using an IoC container and then implementing an interceptor that modify the behavior of the method call.

Comment: I agree - it's not the easiest, however - it is good practice to use dependency injection for a larger app. If you've got that set up already - the interception is a breeze.